# How to draw lines at an angle & arc in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to draw a fairly basic bird shape. I'm using the circle for the body and I'm trying to draw the upper beak (highlighted in red) like shown in the reference image below.

Image reference:

[image]

```
struct Beak: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width/4, y: rect.height/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height/2))
        // draw a line back to the circumference at a given angle
        // & close it with an arc along the circumference of the Body circle
        path.addLine(to: ??) 
        return path
    }
}

struct BirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // MARK: Body
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                .frame(width: 150)
                .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.yellow)
                }
            
            // MARK: Beak
            Beak()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(.orange)
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for the beak to also close with an arc along the circumference of the body circle so that I can animate it later with rotation to simulate the beak open/close. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `.addArc` to draw the curved bit then there's not much to it. It's perhaps easier if you use the middle point for the start of the arc and then move the final shape into position using `.offset`. This also prepares the way for adding a rotation effect later.

To keep the features of the bird head together, you could either apply them all as overlays to the base circle, or you could build them up in a separate `ZStack`. Doing it in a separate `ZStack` is perhaps simpler, the frame size of this `ZStack` can be used to determine the size of the circle as well as the eye and beak.

Here's the adapted `Shape`:

```swift
struct Beak: Shape {
    let angleDegrees: CGFloat
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY),
            radius: rect.midX,
            startAngle: .degrees(180),
            endAngle: .degrees(180 + angleDegrees),
            clockwise: angleDegrees < 0
        )
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.midY))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

And here's how you can use it. I couldn't resist animating it

```swift
struct BirdView: View {
    @State private var gapeAngle = Angle.zero

    private func birdHead(diameter: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(.yellow)

            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5)

            // Eye
            Ellipse()
                .fill(.black)
                .frame(width: diameter / 5, height: diameter / 5.55)
                .offset(x: -diameter / 4.7, y: -diameter / 5.35)

            // Upper beak
            Beak(angleDegrees: 20)
                .stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 5, lineJoin: .round))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .offset(x: -diameter / 2)
                .rotationEffect(gapeAngle)

            // Lower beak
            Beak(angleDegrees: -20)
                .stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 5, lineJoin: .round))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .offset(x: -diameter / 2)
                .rotationEffect(-gapeAngle)
        }
        .frame(width: diameter, height: diameter)
    }

    var body: some View {
        birdHead(diameter: 150)
            .padding(.leading, 50)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .background(.orange)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    gapeAngle = .degrees(5)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah adding the arc first is definitely easier; was probably too late at night to strike me lol. The animation is cool as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the math to figure out how to draw the arc, I would just use [`subtracting`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/subtracting(_:eofill:)) to "subtract" the circle from a right-angled triangle.

```
struct Beak: Shape {
    let radius: CGFloat // this is the radius of the circle to be subtracted
    let angle: Angle
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // first draw a right-angled triangle where the two short edges
        // intersect at the middle of rect
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        let ratio = tan(angle.radians)
        let height = ratio * rect.width / 2
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY - height))
        path.closeSubpath()

        // then create the circle
        let circle = Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(
            x: rect.midX - radius,
            y: rect.midY - radius,
            width: radius * 2,
            height: radius * 2
        ))
        return path.subtracting(circle)
    }
}
```

Then the beak and body can be combined like this:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        // MARK: Body
        Circle()
            .fill(.yellow)
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                Circle()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
            }
            .frame(width: 150)
        
        // MARK: Beak
        Beak(radius: 75, angle: .degrees(16))
            .stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 5, lineJoin: .round))
            .padding(5)
        
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .background(.orange)
}
```

Notes:

- I put the stroked circle above the filled circle to make it easier to reason about where the circle's stroke is, and how thick it is, making aligning the strokes of the two paths easier.
- I used a `.round` line join to stroke the beak, because a miter join looks terrible
- I added some padding around the beak, so that the stroke doesn't go beyond the orange background.

Output:

[image]